# Can the remainder $r_2$ in the following be larger than $\frac{r_0}{2}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $n$ and $r_0 < n$ be integers. We define:

$r_1 = n$ mod $r_0$

$r_2 = n$ mod $r_1$

Where we restrict $0 < r_1 < r_0$ and $0 < r_2 < r_1$. Is it possible for $r_2$ to be larger than $ceil(\frac{1}{2}r_0)$?

Comment: Take $n=29$ and $r_0=6$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The smallest $n$ for which this occurs is $19$, for which we have both $(n,r_0) = (19,5)$ and $(n,r_0) = (19,7)$. The next solution is $(n,r_0) = (27,10)$. The solutions get more and more frequent after that, and occur near certain fractions of $n$, e.g., $r_0 \approx \frac38n$. This works because then $r_1 \approx \frac14n$. We want $r_1$ to be strictly greater than $\frac14n$, so that $r_2 \approx \frac14n > \frac12(\frac38n).$

The value $\frac38$ can be generalized; consider $r_0 = kn$ for these values of $k$:

$$k = \frac38 = \frac3{2(3)+2}\\
k = \frac4{15} = \frac4{3(4)+3}\\
k = \frac5{18} = \frac5{3(5)+3}\\
k = \frac7{32} = \frac7{4(7)+4}\\
\ldots
$$

Finally, here are all the solutions for $1 \leq n \leq 100$. The horizontal rows go from $r_0 = 1$ to $r_0 = \frac n2$, and an "x" indicates a solution.

```
  1  
  2  .
  3  .
  4  ..
  5  ..
  6  ...
  7  ...
  8  ....
  9  ....
 10  .....
 11  .....
 12  ......
 13  ......
 14  .......
 15  .......
 16  ........
 17  ........
 18  .........
 19  ....x.x..
 20  ..........
 21  ..........
 22  ...........
 23  ...........
 24  ............
 25  ............
 26  .............
 27  .........x...
 28  ..............
 29  .....x........
 30  ..........x....
 31  ...............
 32  ................
 33  ................
 34  ......x.x........
 35  ............x....
 36  ..................
 37  ..................
 38  .........x...x.....
 39  ....x..............
 40  ....................
 41  ......x.......x.....
 42  ..........x..........
 43  ...............x.....
 44  ......................
 45  ......................
 46  ................x......
 47  .......x....x..........
 48  ........................
 49  ............x....x......
 50  .........................
 51  ..................x......
 52  ..................x.......
 53  ........x.x..x............
 54  ......x............x.......
 55  .......x...................
 56  ............................
 57  ..............x.....x.......
 58  ...........x.................
 59  ....xx...............x.......
 60  .....................x........
 61  ........x...x..x..............
 62  ........x.x...........x........
 63  ..........x.x.........x........
 64  ................x...............
 65  ................xx.....x........
 66  .................................
 67  ........................x........
 68  .............x...x......x.........
 69  .........x........................
 70  .........................x.........
 71  ........x................x.........
 72  ..................x.................
 73  ..............x...........x.........
 74  ..........................x..........
 75  ...............x...........x.........
 76  ......x...x.x......xx......x..........
 77  ...............x......................
 78  .........x..................x..........
 79  ....x....x..........x.......x..........
 80  ....................x...................
 81  .............................x..........
 82  .............x..x............x...........
 83  ......x..............xx.......x..........
 84  .....................x........x...........
 85  ..............................x...........
 86  ..............x................x...........
 87  ..........x......xx...x........x...........
 88  ............x.x.......x.....................
 89  .....xx..x........x.............x...........
 90  ................................x............
 91  .......................x.........x...........
 92  ..................x..............x............
 93  .................................x............
 94  ...............x........xx........x............
 95  ...........x............x.........x............
 96  ..................................x.............
 97  ........xxx........x...............x............
 98  ..........x..............x.........x.............
 99  ....x....................x..........x............
100  ................x...................x.............
```